# Getting the information from my database and write them in a JTable. Error: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 2

Tags: java

I try to create a list of "user" from my database and add them to my JTable.

I get the error message:

```
"java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 2
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
    at Administration.User_Verwalten.show_user(User_Verwalten.java:83)
    at Administration.User_Verwalten.<init>(User_Verwalten.java:189)
    at Administration.User_Verwalten$1.run(User_Verwalten.java:62)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)"
```

I already checked the ArrayList, but I do not find any mistake. I already read a thread about this error message where the mistake was in the for-loop, but here the for-loop is correct. 
Here is the code:

```
ArrayList <User> list = connect.getAllFromUserAsUser();
            DefaultTableModel model1 = (DefaultTableModel) tableUsers.getModel();
            Object [] row = new Object[7];
            for (int i=0; i<=list.size();i++) {
            row [0] = list.get(i).getID();
            row [1] = list.get(i).getBenutzername();
            row [2] = list.get(i).getPasswort();
            row [3] = list.get(i).getName();
            row [4] = list.get(i).getVorname();
            row [5] = list.get(i).getGeburtsdatum();
            row [6] = list.get(i).isIstWirt();
            model1.addRow(row);
            }



public ArrayList<User> getAllFromUserAsUser() throws SQLException { //prüft ob eingegebene LoginID in DB ist
        ArrayList <User> All = new ArrayList <User>(); 
        try {
            String query = "select ID,Benutzername,Passwort,Name,Vorname,Geburtsdatum,IstWirt from user";
            rs= st.executeQuery(query);
            User user;
            while (rs.next()) {
                user= new User(rs.getInt("ID"), rs.getString("Benutzername"), rs.getString("Passwort"),rs.getString("Name"),
                        rs.getString("Vorname"),rs.getDate("Geburtsdatum"),rs.getBoolean("IstWirt"));

                All.add(user);
                }
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        finally {
            if (rs!=null) {rs.close();
            }
        }
        return All;

    }
```

Comment: `for (int i=0; i<=list.size();i++) {` is the most immediate issue.  `List` is indexed as `0` to `size - 1`, so it should be `for (int i=0; i<list.size();i++)`

Comment: I searched for so long, but could not find the mistake. Thank you very much!

Comment: It would recommend looking at [enhanced or `for-each` loops](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) (look to towards the bottom) and [The try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in for loop condition `i<=list.size();i++)`
if you have an array of size 4, then you need a max of 4 iterations, so for example i=0,1,2,3. That is 4 iterations so stop condition is the size of the array - 1.
the for loop should be for `(int i=0; i<list.size();i++) {`.